# How to FadeIn a parent element and then it's child elements with a slight Delay (CSS Only)

Tags: css, css-animations

I want to `fadein` the body element and then `fadein` one of it's child with a slight delay.

I've tried this but it's not working

```
body {
    animation: fadein 0.5s;
}

header {
    animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

I've also tried using `animation-delay` but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body {
  animation: fadein 0.5s forwards; /* use forwards to maintain the last  keyframe state */
}

header {
  opacity:0;      /* You need this initial opacity */
  animation: fadein 2s 1s forwards; /* 1s is the delay */
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

P.S: not sure if `body` is the best parent option, but here's an example that uses a DIV parent:

```css
html, body{height:100%;}

#page {
  height:100%;
  background:green;
  animation: fadein 0.5s forwards;
}

header {
  opacity:0;
  animation: fadein 2s 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <header>THIS IS HEADER</header>
</div>
```

Comment: The `2s` I used in my code, That was supposed to be the delay. I am confused by the 2s you used here. I actually don't know how the numbers are working. so the first one is the transition duration and the second is the actual delay?

Comment: @xperator exactly. above `2s` (and `0.5s`) is the `animation-duration` property, and the `1s` (if you use it) is the `animation-delay` property value.

Comment: Thx! oh and the reason I used body tag is that I wanted to add an animation when the page contents load. I don't even know if this is the right way. We are setting `opacity` of header to `0` and I'm not sure if thats safe? any compatibility issues?

Comment: great concern. Yes. Setting it to 0 as default you risk non CSS3 compatible browsers to never trigger the animation therefore never revealing that element.